# Element UI select item is not dynamically setting the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using element UI in my project and I am loading countries dynamically from an API, and the pattern for it is like:

```
{
country: "Afghanistan"
country_id: 1
nationality: "Afghans"
}
```

```
<el-select class="abctest" v-model="value" placeholder="Country" @change="updateDropdowns(index, $event)">
  <el-option v-for="item in country_data" :key="item.country_id" :label="item.country" :value="item.country_id">
  </el-option>
</el-select>
```

Thats the select I am doing, and this is how I am getting the ID from the database like `country_id=1`.

If I bind that with value, it just print the 1. I need the country name selected, any idea how I can do that?

I am using VueJS 2 and ElementUI 2.

It's not selecting any country which is coming from database.

Comment: When I run your code it seems to work fine. Best guess is that your types don't match, so you might be using numbers in one place and strings in the other. If that isn't the problem we'll need a complete, minimal test case because the problem isn't reproducible just using the code you provided.

Comment: @skirtle yes thats the problem thanks i have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is fixed. Problem is the response of api. its giving me country_id in string i just convert it into integer and it works

Answer (score 0):

Just change `:value="item.country_id"` to `:value="item.country"`